# How to get multiple nodes with jquery

Tags: jquery

While for a single element we can use jQuery('#elem').get(0), is there a way we can get the node elements for multiple selection:

like: jQuery('.elements').getAll(0) ?

I'm looking for a solution, if exists, without a loop iteration.

Comment: What would you have them returned as? An array, collection, object?

Comment: As jQuery('#elem').get(0) returns the actual dom node, I am looking for a jQuery method, or a cool way to retrieve the dom nodes when selecting multiple elements without going though them within a loop.

Comment: Allan Jardine has already provided you with a way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No single method to do that exists. The only other option you have is to get *all* of the matched nodes, by not passing an argument to [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
var all = jQuery('.elements').get();
```

However, you could reduce the matched set down to the elements you require before calling `.get()` to acheive the same thing. You can use [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to return a subset of the matched elements between two indicies:

```
var all = jQuery('.elements').slice(1, 3).get();
```

Other than that, your best bet will probably be to use some form of iteration (e.g. [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)) to return the elements at specific indicies, and the use `.get()` again:

```
var all = jQuery('.elements').filter(function (i) {
    return i === 2 || i === 5 || i === 9;
}).get();
```

Comment: however, jQuery('.elements').get(); will return the jquery objects not the dom nodes.

Comment: @user1134422 - No, it returns an array of DOM nodes.

Comment: @user1134422 There are no jQuery objects, only jQuery collections.

Comment: James - You are absolutely right. 
var divs = jQuery('div').get();
divs[4].getAttribute('id'); // works

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the selection...

For single class

```
$('.elements').get() // It will return all the DOM elements have class="elements <other_classes>"
```

For multiple classes

```
$('.elements, .nav, .address').get() // It will get all the DOM elements has either of these classes.
```

Comment: Have I completely misunderstood the question? How does this help with retrieving multiple DOM nodes from an existing jQuery object?

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking. He already has a jQuery collection from `jQuery('.elements').`, he wants to return a NodeList.

Comment: I thought he is looking for selection so that he can get the DOM elements from it by calling .get() method. Any way i can edit to get the DOM elements.

Comment: Asad is right, I am looking for the dom node not the jQuery objects.